# How to give border to this react tooltip and remove the arrow?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tooltip, react-tooltip

How can we remove arrow of this react tooltip and give it a border?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can by overide tooltip css, try this

```
<span data-tip="hello" data-class="tool-tip"></span>

.tool-tip::before {
  border-right: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.__react_component_tooltip::before,
.__react_component_tooltip::after {
  content: none !important;
}
```